# Creating a loop to process all csv files and produce one figure with subplots per file

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob

path="/Users/My_Comp/Desktop/python_for_marine_data-master/week_2/USNDBC_62030/*.csv"
df = pd.DataFrame()

for fname in glob.iglob(path):
    if file=='*.csv':
    df = df.append(pd.read_csv(file,sep=';',index_col=[0],skiprows=[1],parse_dates={'DateTime': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]}))
    df.drop(['WDIR','WSPD','GST','WVHT','DPD','APD','MWD','WTMP','VIS','PTDY','TIDE'],axis=1,inplace=True)
fig1,ax1=plt.subplots(3,1,sharex=True)
df.plot(kind='line',y='PRES',ax=ax1[0])
df.plot(kind='line',y='ATMP',ax=ax1[1])
df.plot(kind='line',y='DEWP',ax=ax1[2])
plt.xticks(rotation=17)
plt.show()
```

Sorry, I'm new to python and can't quite figure how to get this to work. So currently, it runs fine, however, it only produces one plot with no data displayed. I'm trying to, albeit poorly, create a loop to read all .csv files in the directory, then create a figure with 3 subplots for each file. hope that helps. Any help or information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide an explanation of the current behaviour along with a description of the desired behaviour.

Comment: sorry. so currently it runs, however it only produces one plot with no data displayed. I'm trying to, albeit poorly, create a loop to read all .csv files in the directory, then create a figure with 3 subplots for each file. hope that helps.

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: thanks for the advice, have done.

Comment: Notice that after `if file==...` you should indent.

Comment: The line `if file=='*.csv':` does not seem to make any sense. Remove that. Then indent the code correctly, if the plotting happend outside the loop, it will only produce one plot, if inside, it produces several. As to why no data is plotted, one cannot know. See [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, that was perfect. Truly appreciate the help it now works perfectly!